# How can I solve the following problems in log4cpp?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, log4cpp

I'm trying to compile log4cpp in visual studio 2008 but I'm getting some errors like these:

```
Error   26  error C2664: 'ReportEventW' : cannot convert parameter 8 from 'const char *[1]' to 'LPCWSTR *' ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\nteventlogappender.cpp    64
Error   19 error C2676: binary '+' : 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   11  error C2782: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   10  error C2782: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   18  error C2784: 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'WCHAR [260]'  ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   16  error C2784: 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::difference_type,std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   15  error C2784: 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::difference_type,std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   7   error C2784: 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<_Sizet,_Difft,_MycontTy> std::operator +(_Difft,std::_Vb_const_iterator<_Sizet,_Difft,_MycontTy>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<_Sizet,_Difft,_MycontTy>' from 'WCHAR [260]' ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   6   error C2784: 'std::_Vb_iterator<_Sizet,_Difft,_MycontTy> std::operator +(_Difft,std::_Vb_iterator<_Sizet,_Difft,_MycontTy>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vb_iterator<_Sizet,_Difft,_MycontTy>' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   9   error C2784: 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::operator +(_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>::difference_type,std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   8   error C2784: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::operator +(_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>::difference_type,std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   13  error C2784: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'  ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   12  error C2784: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(const _Elem,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   14  error C2784: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
Error   17  error C2784: 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> std::operator +(_Diff,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'WCHAR [260]'   ...\testlog4cppdll\log4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp 127
```

Here is the code:

```
 hFind = FindFirstFile(LPTSTR(pattern.c_str()), &ffd); //Ahrost
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            struct stat statBuf;
            const std::string fullfilename = dirname + PATHDELIMITER + ffd.cFileName;
            int res = ::stat(fullfilename.c_str(), &statBuf);
            if (res != -1 && statBuf.st_mtime < oldest && !(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
                std::cout << "Deleting " << fullfilename << "\n";
                ::unlink(fullfilename.c_str());
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            // [XXX] some kind of error happened
        }
        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
```

The entire source of file  is:

```
#include "PortabilityImpl.hh"
#ifdef LOG4CPP_HAVE_IO_H
#    include <io.h>
#endif
#ifdef LOG4CPP_HAVE_UNISTD_H
#    include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <log4cpp/DailyRollingFileAppender.hh>
#include <log4cpp/Category.hh>
#include <log4cpp/FactoryParams.hh>
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <time.h> //Ahrost

#ifdef LOG4CPP_HAVE_SSTREAM
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#endif

#ifndef WIN32    // only available on Win32
#include <dirent.h>
#endif

namespace log4cpp {

    unsigned int DailyRollingFileAppender::maxDaysToKeepDefault = 30;

    DailyRollingFileAppender::DailyRollingFileAppender(const std::string& name,
                                             const std::string& fileName, 
                                             unsigned int maxDaysToKeep,
                                             bool append,
                                             mode_t mode) :
        FileAppender(name, fileName, append, mode),
        _maxDaysToKeep(maxDaysToKeep != 0 ? maxDaysToKeep : maxDaysToKeepDefault) {
        struct stat statBuf;
        int res;
        time_t t;

        // obtain last modification time
        res = ::stat(fileName.c_str(), &statBuf);
        if (res < 0) {
            t = time(NULL);
        } else {
            t = statBuf.st_mtime;
        }
#ifndef WIN32    // only available on Win32
        localtime_r(&t, &_logsTime);
#else
        localtime_s(&_logsTime, &t);
#endif
    }

    void DailyRollingFileAppender::setMaxDaysToKeep(unsigned int maxDaysToKeep) {
        _maxDaysToKeep = maxDaysToKeep;
    }

    unsigned int DailyRollingFileAppender::getMaxDaysToKeep() const {
        return _maxDaysToKeep;
    }

    void DailyRollingFileAppender::rollOver()
    {
        std::ostringstream filename_s;
        ::close(_fd);
        filename_s << _fileName << "." << _logsTime.tm_year + 1900 << "-"
                        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << _logsTime.tm_mon + 1 << "-"
                        << std::setw(2) << _logsTime.tm_mday << std::ends;
        const std::string lastFn = filename_s.str();
        ::rename(_fileName.c_str(), lastFn.c_str());

        _fd = ::open(_fileName.c_str(), _flags, _mode);

        const time_t oldest = time(NULL) - _maxDaysToKeep * 60 * 60 * 24;

#ifndef WIN32 
#define PATHDELIMITER "/" 
#else 
#define PATHDELIMITER "\\"
#endif
        // iterate over files around log file and delete older with same prefix
        const std::string::size_type last_delimiter = _fileName.rfind(PATHDELIMITER);
        const std::string dirname((last_delimiter == std::string::npos)? "." : _fileName.substr(0, last_delimiter));
        const std::string filname((last_delimiter == std::string::npos)? _fileName : _fileName.substr(last_delimiter+1, _fileName.size()-last_delimiter-1));
#ifndef WIN32    // only available on Win32
        struct dirent **entries;
        int nentries = scandir(dirname.c_str(), &entries, 0, alphasort);
        if (nentries < 0)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < nentries; i++) {
            struct stat statBuf;
            int res = ::stat(entries[i]->d_name, &statBuf);
            if ((res == -1) || (!S_ISREG(statBuf.st_mode))) {
                free(entries[i]);
                continue;
            }
            if (statBuf.st_mtime < oldest && strstr(entries[i]->d_name, filname.c_str())) {
                const std::string fullfilename = dirname + PATHDELIMITER + entries[i]->d_name;
                ::unlink(fullfilename.c_str());
                std::cout << " Deleting " << fullfilename.c_str() << std::endl;
            }
            free(entries[i]);
        }
        free(entries);
#else
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    const std::string pattern = _fileName + "*";

    hFind = FindFirstFile(LPTSTR(pattern.c_str()), &ffd); //Ahrost
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            struct stat statBuf;
            const std::string fullfilename = dirname + PATHDELIMITER + ffd.cFileName;
            int res = ::stat(fullfilename.c_str(), &statBuf);
            if (res != -1 && statBuf.st_mtime < oldest && !(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
                std::cout << "Deleting " << fullfilename << "\n";
                ::unlink(fullfilename.c_str());
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            // [XXX] some kind of error happened
        }
        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
#endif
    }

    void DailyRollingFileAppender::_append(const log4cpp::LoggingEvent &event)
    {
        struct tm now;
        time_t t = time(NULL);

#ifndef WIN32    // only available on Win32
        bool timeok = localtime_r(&t, &now) != NULL;
#else
        bool timeok = localtime_s(&now, &t) == 0;
#endif
        if (timeok) {
            if ((now.tm_mday != _logsTime.tm_mday) ||
                (now.tm_mon != _logsTime.tm_mon) ||
                (now.tm_year != _logsTime.tm_year)) {
                rollOver();
                _logsTime = now;
            }
        }
        log4cpp::FileAppender::_append(event);
    }

   std::auto_ptr<Appender> create_daily_roll_file_appender(const FactoryParams& params)
   {
      std::string name, filename;
      bool append = true;
      mode_t mode = 664;
      unsigned int max_days_keep = 0;
      params.get_for("daily roll file appender").required("name", name)("filename", filename)("max_days_keep", max_days_keep)
                                          .optional("append", append)("mode", mode);

      return std::auto_ptr<Appender>(new DailyRollingFileAppender(name, filename, max_days_keep, append, mode));
   }
}
```

Above source belong to DailyRollingFileAppender.cpp file which is one of the log4cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mix-up of narrow and wide strings.

Your use of character types with letter T in the name (like LPTSTR) implies that the code can work with either narrow or wide chars, depending on the _UNICODE setting. However, you use std::string types too, which are explicitly narrow, and tring literals without wide-char specifier L.

If your code SHOULD be available in both narrow and wide favors, make sure you use TEXT() or _T() macros to form the appropriate string.